# python executing error on emacs (ImportError: No module named site)

Tags: python, emacs, centos

I'm trying to execute my python code on emacs.

when I try c-c c-c, the following errors occur.

```
ImportError: No module named siteCould not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

so I set pythonpath in .emacs file as follows :

```
(setenv "PYTHONPATH" "/opt/python2.7/bin")
```

but still error pops.

any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do you have more than one Python installed?

Comment: After trying it, what is the output of `print(sys.path)` ?

Comment: @Keith I installed new one and deleted the old one, so there exists only one.

Comment: my sys.path output : ['', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Comment: That's unusual. what does `ls /opt/python2.7` show?

Comment: 4 directories - bin, include, lib, share

Comment: Well, that's completely wrong. Try re-installing Python.

Comment: thanks. do you know any proper material to install python 2.7 on CentOS? or any documents about what is not wrong about python?

Comment: Which version of CentOS?

Comment: it's 5.5. actually I followed this article : http://villaroad.com/2010/10/rolling-python-2-6-2-on-centos-5-3/ , which turns out not to work with emacs anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just install Python 2.7 using the following RPM:

ftp://ftp.pycopia.org/pub/python/centos/5/i386/python2.7-2.7.1-1TH.i386.rpm

It should work on any CentOS 5.x, 32 bit.  You don't have to remove the "stock" Python2.4, this one co-exists with the standard installation. It won't break your system installing this RPM.  You do, however, have to be explicit with the version in your pound-bang line.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# Your python script
```

There are other RPMs there you might also want to install.